# ASPX Textbox: Execute method on return keypress

Tags: .net, asp.net, textbox

I have a search box that doesn't have a submit button, I need to be able to hit enter and then execute a method, how do I do this?

Comment: is this a client-side method or a server-side method?

Comment: hi, it needs to be server side, no javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could also do something simple like this with CSS:

```
<asp:Panel DefaultButton="myButton" runat="server">
    <asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" runat="server" />
    <asp:Button ID="myButton" runat="server" onclick="myButton_Click" style="display: none; "  />
</asp:Panel>
```

The panel may or may not be necessary depending on your implementation and surrounding controls, but this works and does a postback for me.

Comment: In my experience, the DefaultButton property doesn't work outside of IE

Comment: Upon further investigation, that may just be when the button is a LinkButton that it doesn't work outside IE...

Comment: hmm... I never knew about that limitation for linkbutton... Thanks!
Good article here describing it and a workaround for it: 
http://kpumuk.info/asp-net/using-panel-defaultbutton-property-with-linkbutton-control-in-asp-net/

Answer (score 2):

You could add a hidden button to the page and wire-up your method to that button's click event.  Then add a small bit of javascript to trigger that button's postback action when you press enter inside the textbox.

```
this.myTextBox.Attributes.Add(
    "onkeydown", 
    "return keyDownHandler(13, 'javascript:" 
     + this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.myButton, string.Empty).Replace("'", "%27") 
     + "', event);");
```

(You could also replace the hard-coded 13 with [Windows.Forms.Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys.aspx).Enter, if you'd prefer an easier to read version.)

Where keyDownHandler is a JavaScript function like this:

```
function keyDownHandler(iKeyCode, sFunc, e) { 
    if (e == null) { 
        e = window.event; 
    } 
    if (e.keyCode == iKeyCode) { 
        eval(unescape(sFunc)); return false; 
    } 
}
```

Note, this is based on the implementation of [DotNetNuke](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/)'s [ClientAPI web utility](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Products/Development/Forge/ComponentClientAPI/tabid/851/Default.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use the TextChanged event, and set the AutoPostBack property to true.

Comment: This fires off the event from just putting a character in there and clicking off the textbox, is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: Not really.  TextChanged will be fired when you hit return in the text box, or when the text box loses focus.  (Assuming the text has actually changed.)  Sorry, but it's just the way it works.  Otherwise, you would need to use javascript and handle it all yourself.